# How right testing compound string children in react-native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have next code:

```
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const BaseTitle = styled.Text`
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #111;
`;

function Title({ title }) {
  return <BaseTitle>№{title}</BaseTitle>;
}
```

How to correctly check the string that should have the character № and the transferred string?

```
test("Title render", () => {
  const tree = shallow(<Title title="123123" />);
  expect(?????).toContain("№123123");
});
```

Comment: Could you give more details ? This is really unclear (to me)

Comment: @Treycos I render my component use `shallow`. And i don't know what I need to write in `expect` to get the value that I can check with line `"№123123"`. Example: `.toContain("№123123")` or `.toBe("№123123")`. If write `expect(tree.text()).toContain("№123123");` then test returned false.

Comment: I can tested only prop title: `expect(tree.props().title).toBe('123123');`. But i need testing that component has child `"№123123"`